# .Net Core Identity User not populated when using OpenIdConnect

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, openid-connect

I'm implementing OpenIdConnect into a .Net Core app, which associates an external login with a user stored in an internal (default Identity) database, and attempts to log in. The log in method reports success, but the User object isn't populated.
The login process was scaffolded in, so it's all boilerplate, including the external login process.

I'd appreciate any help in understanding what I'm doing wrong.

[image: log in succeeded]

[image: user not populated]

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = "oidc";
            options.DefaultSignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme;
        })
            .AddCookie()
            .AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
            {
                options.Authority = oauthSettings.Location.AbsoluteUri;
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                options.ClientId = oauthSettings.ClientID;
                options.ClientSecret = oauthSettings.ClientSecret;
                options.ResponseType = "id_token token";

                options.Scope.Add("openid");
                options.Scope.Add("profile");
                options.Scope.Add("email");
            });

//In Login.cshtml.cs
 public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
    {
        returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");

        ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
            // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, set lockoutOnFailure: true
            var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.Email, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");
                return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
            }
            if (result.RequiresTwoFactor)
            {
                return RedirectToPage("./LoginWith2fa", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = Input.RememberMe });
            }
            if (result.IsLockedOut)
            {
                _logger.LogWarning("User account locked out.");
                return RedirectToPage("./Lockout");
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
                return Page();
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return Page();
    }
```

EDIT: I've found that when I remove the AddAuthentication method in Startup the login works, but obviously that disabled the external auth. Something about adding OpenIdConnect is breaking the login process.

Comment: Please replace screenshots with code snippets.

Comment: @tmsbrndz I've replaced one with code, the others are debug results

Comment: Can you show the code around your `PasswordSignInAsync`?  I almost think you need `ExternalLoginSignInAsync ` or `HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync();`.

Comment: I've added that, but it's boilerplate so I'd be surprised if that was the issue. The scaffolded code has external login capability built in.

Comment: Aside from obtaining a list of the registered external schemes, all that code handles is password login. Unfortunately I'm on the verge of falling asleep so I can't really help too much.

Comment: It should also be populating the user. That's what enables other pages to signal that we're authenticated. At the moment it just redirects back to the login as soon as it reaches the other page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this I did the following in the startup:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = "oidc";
        options.DefaultSignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme;
    })
        .AddCookie()
        .AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
        {
            options.Authority = oauthSettings.Location.AbsoluteUri;
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            options.ClientId = oauthSettings.ClientID;
            options.ClientSecret = oauthSettings.ClientSecret;
            options.ResponseType = "id_token token";

            options.Scope.Add("openid");
            options.Scope.Add("profile");
            options.Scope.Add("email");
        });
```

So I left it to its defaults and it worked. I'm not 100% why.